# Time complexity of functions Omega, O, and Theta

Tags: c, time, time-complexity

```
void Q2a(int N) 
{
    int j, k;
    for (j = 1; j <= N; j *= 3) 
        for (k = 1; k <= N; k *= 2) 
            printf(" SC1007 \n");
}
```

Can someone help to explain the time complexity? I understand the simple concepts and definition of O, omega and theta. As well as the scenario where the for loop just runs for n-1 times (int i = 1; i<n; i++). But when conditions such as this comes out, I'm totally lost. Online videos always seem to write random equations to start things off. I know which means upper, lower and average case etc and how they come about. But when I look at algorithms, how do I start ? This question asks for the big theta of the function. The solution to this is :

inner loop: 
2^(K−1) ≤ N < 2^K 
(K − 1) ≤ log2(N) < K 
K ≤ log2 N + 1 < K + 1 
K = ⌊log2 N + 1⌋ = ⌊log2 N⌋ + 1

Where does the first line come from?

Answer (score 0):

> Where does the first line come from?

The first line is “2^(K−1) ≤ N < 2^K ”. In the inner loop, we have for `(k = 1; k <= N; k *= 2)`. The values `k` takes on in this loop are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32,…, namely 2<sup>*K*</sup> in iteration number *K* (starting with 0).

If `k <= N` is true, the loop continues. Once it is false, the loop stops. If the loop stops before iteration *K*, then 2<sup>*K*</sup> ≤ *N* is false, so *N* < 2<sup>*K*</sup>. And, since the loop did not stop on the previous iteration, *K*−1, it must be that 2<sup>*K*−1</sup> ≤ *N* is true (supposing that the loop executed at least one iteration, so that there is a previous iteration).

Therefore 2<sup>*K*−1</sup> ≤ *N* < 2<sup>*K*</sup>.